# ThreeJS Texture isn't matching original render

Tags: javascript, three.js

Here are some screenshots to describe my issue:

This is the orignal render of the .glb file and its quality.
[image: Original Render]

This is what it looks like rendered in the browser, if you look at the brim of the hat he's wearing you can see their appears to be some texture issues. Also if you rotate the head you'll see that the model itself will have parts of you can see through.
[image: Browser Render]

Here's my code I'm using, you'll see that I'm trying to change the gamma and also use proper techniques to better apply the textures.

```
function ( gltf ) {
gltf.scene.traverse( function ( child ) {
  if ( child.isMesh ) {
    child.material.alphaTest = .5;
    child.material.map.anisotropy = maxAnisotropy;
  }
} );
scene.add( gltf.scene );
this.renderer.gammaOutput = true;
this.renderer.gammaInput = true;
this.renderer.gammaFactor = 2.2;
this.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding
this.anisotropy = maxAnisotropy;
this.mipmaps = true;
gltf.animations; // Array<THREE.AnimationClip>
gltf.scene; // THREE.Group
gltf.scenes; // Array<THREE.Group>
gltf.cameras; // Array<THREE.Camera>
gltf.asset; // Object
},
```

Please let me know what you think I should do to get this model to load with higher quality.

Comment: You should not configure `gammeInput` or `gammaOutput` anymore. Define the output color space with `WebGLRenderer.outputEncoding`. In your case, apply `THREE.sRGBEncoding`. Besides, what is the reason for configuring `alphaTest`?

Comment: What do you mean there are texture issues? Your screenshots look almost identical to me, could you elaborate what the issue is? Also, if there are transparency issues, you should demonstrate them.